# Execute script in VBA Excel (selenium)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I thank you infinitely

the problem that the web application in which I want to run the script uses the form bootstrap, the latter is not compatible with the Internet Explore.
that's why I want to use selenium to excute the script 
the code fonctionne perfectly when i execute code below in console element (inspect)

```
$('#form-classe').select2().val($('#form-classe option:contains("texte)").val()).trigger('change');
```

the code allows to select the value "text" in the bootstrap form

But the problem that i want to excute the code by VBA excel, I try to use the bellow selenium methode

```
 Dim webdriver As New WebDriver  
webdriver.ExecuteScript "$('#form-classe').select2().val($('#form-classe option:contains('texte)').val()).trigger('change');"
```

Comment: Can you share the url? Or more of the html? Looks like jquery

Comment: Think you for help. I edit the question to give more explination.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error ?
Where is the rest of code ? 
I can help you with more informations

With Ie object should work..

```
dim ie as object
set ie =createObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'...ie.navigate ...
call ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript ("$('#form-classe').select2().val($('#form-classe option:contains('texte)').val()).trigger('change');")
```

Try calling it with CALL
call webdriver.ExecuteScript ()

Comment: Think you for help.  I edit the question to give more explination, 
when I use call: 

Call webdriver.ExecuteScript("$('#form-classe').select2().val($('#form-classe option:contains('texte)').val()).trigger('change');")
I have the error bellow (' Run Time '17' JavaScriptError missing ) after argument list)

Comment: the function .executeScript(Script,Arguments)  , webdriver is not understanding the Jquery , he is thinking that arguments is necessary to replace in some variable in the function. You can try to do it , with Original JS


document.getElementById('form-classe')
and them run each options
for each opt in  document.getElementById('form-classe').options
   opt.selected = true
'and them after that 
document.getElementById('form-classe').trigger('onchange')